# HTML form is not working well with form input

Tags: php, html

This is my simple html from.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Save your Contact form: <br>
    <textarea name="code" placeholder="Write your form html" rows="30" cols="100">
        <?php if(isset($_POST['code'])){ echo htmlentities($_POST['code']) ; } ?>
    </textarea>
    <br>
    Password<br>
    <input type="password" name="password"><br>
    <button type="submit">Create</button>
</form>
```

Output of it is:
[image]

Now put sample input in the form code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
</form>
```

Now press "Create" button 2 times. First time it is ok. But in the second time I am getting unexpected output.  How to solve this problem?
[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGGbM.jpg):

Comment: echo htmlentities($_POST['code']) ?

Comment: I have tried this too. But no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
put header("X-XSS-Protection: 0"); after if(isset($_POST['code'])){ 
this issue is due to XSS Auditor refused to execute a script
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Following code for button

```
<button type="submit">Create</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I assume after submission of the form data is being sent to `.php` script and then gets manipulated.
2. Why are clicking on `Submit buttom` more than once? even though you are doing it - are you checking if same data is getting submitted ?
3. **Most important** - you should have proper **`VALIDATION`** rules in place through JS or PHP to prevent any problems on form submission.

Comment: User will write code here. Also there is password area. If user types wrong password, then his code will be gone without this way. By this way, he will be able to rewrite password without loosing code.

Comment: Your question did not explain this earlier. :( Please make sure that you be as descriptive as possible.

Comment: I made my question easier to understand. I described only the requirement because it is a very small portion of a very large application. So, I did not try to make my question unnecessarily large.